# netbeans 8.0.2 - can not print utf-8 characters correctly

Tags: java, netbeans, utf-8

As title says, I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2, on Windows 7 OS. I saw many different topics about this and tried different solutions, but none really helped.

So characters like [š, ć, đ, ž, È, æ] are displayed as � or squared, depending on the font. Here is what I've tried:

- I have set `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in `../etc/netbeans.conf`
- I've checked project settings and encoding is set to utf-8

[image]

- When I'm reading file, I'm using following code:

  `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));`
  or with `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` or `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` or `Charset.forName("ISO8859-2")` nothing helped.

Any one has idea what other problem could be ?

Comment: What character encoding set is your OS using? Have you tried setting it to `en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: How can I check it in Windows 7 if is set to it ?

Comment: Check the control panel somewhere like here: control panel / system / advanced system settings / advanced / environmental variables

Comment: That's not a solution.

Comment: Where, and how, are these characters displayed?

Comment: The location matters.  I've been doing a data parsing project lately and UTF characters display differently depending on the stage of the process through different programs.  I believe in JavaFX TextFields some of them come up as a similar null-character.  If it's in NetBeans itself, it could be a problem at the OS level, if it varies between applications, it could be NetBeans, if it's in output fields for a program, could be local to that instead.

Comment: @JBNizet In Java Console Application, in output.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a small piece of code which demonstrate your problem. What does `System.out.println("\u0161");` print on your console? (should be š).

Comment: `System.out.println("\u0161");` prints š. About a small piece of code, it is nothing else than a `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) { sout(line)... }`

Comment: are you sure the read is OK? I've installed netbeans and ran a simple sample application and all characters are printed as expected with the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that this characters `[š, ć, đ, ž, È, æ]` are type Eastern European (Windows-1250).

So the correct encoding type is `"Windows-1250"`.

Comment: You can use one of encoding detectors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759356/what-is-the-most-accurate-encoding-detector

Comment: Thank you on that, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a Netbeans issue per se, The netbeans `FileAPI` can open files in any encoding. When you don't know what encoding to use you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/javatlacati/netbeans-encoding-plugin) to change the encoding dinamically.

**Update**: you can find the plugin now in the official plugins page as [Encodding Support](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/60487/encoding-support)

Answer (score 2):

#### To read text file with UTF-8 encoding use this code (Java 8):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        ));
```

To find file encoding use one of encoding detectors: [What is the most accurate encoding detector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759356/what-is-the-most-accurate-encoding-detector)

#### To set encoding for your program source code use this settings:

- Netbeans

  ```
  [project settings] / source / encoding = UTF-8
  ```
- Maven:

  ```
  <project>
    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
  </project>
  ```