# Java GB2312 string in HTML does not display correctly

Tags: java, encoding

I am trying to read in HTML from Chinese websites and get their `<title>` value. All the websites with UTF-8 encoding works fine, but not for GB2312 websites (for example, m.39.net, which shows `39������_�й����ȵĽ����Ż���վ` instead of `39健康网_中国领先的健康门户网站`).

Here is the code I use to accomplish that:

```
URL url = new URL(urlstr);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
String content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "GB2312");` may do the help.

If you want to detect the charset of a webpage, there are 3 ways as far as I know:

1. use `connection.getContentEncoding()` to get the charset described in the HTTP header;
2. parse `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">` or `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the HTML code (have to download the HTML content first and then read several lines);
3. use 3rd party libraries. E.g. those mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759356/what-is-the-most-accurate-encoding-detector).

Comment: This would work for the example site, but I need a generic way to determine the site title encoding.

Comment: @WoLfPwNeR I've already updated my answer, hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve the problem using the first 2 bullet points and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

```
toString(byte[] input, String encoding)
```

Comment: Seems like the earlier answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34735065/441757 had already suggested using `IOUtils.toString()`...